# The word "benefit" in Old English or Latin

Tags: single-word-requests, latin

Is there a Latin word for *benefit* or an Old English word? I cannot find any via Google Search, I only get: **Beneficium**, which doesn't look promising.

I am thinking of more marketing/business/technology terms but with some fancy way of putting it on the paper. It's used in the heading, "Introduction", and then after the introduction part, comes "Benefits" except replaced with something fancier.

Does anyone know of any other words?

Comment: *Benefit* in what sense? How are you going to use it?

Comment: Well, [boon](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boon) hearkens back to Middle English, and means a benefit.

Comment: I guess from *beneficium* you want a noun. The tag info for single-word requests says "Please be specific about the intended use of the word." However, *benefit* is not very different from the Middle English *benfit* and probably **does** qualify as an old English or Latin word.

Comment: @StoneyB in context with usage of certain technologies and a products increase of benefits. A little bit hard to explain in deep details.

Comment: @JohnSmith Please edit your question to include an example sentence or two where this word will be used. You may leave a blank (`_____`) in the example sentences where the word you seek will fit. The *less generic* and *more specific* to your particular situation you make then example sentences, the better answers you will attract.

Comment: @DanBron The main problem is that this is a Heading, and not used in a sentence, think: "Introduction" and then another "Benefits" etc. However, I want something more fancy, "Beneficium" is fancy in one way, but I want to know if there are more single word choices.

Comment: Two people have downvoted, presumably because they think "This question does not show any research effort: it is unclear or not useful". You have not done enough research to get the spelling right:: you have not made clear how the word will be used, or whether you want archaic English, Middle English, Old English or Latin (the last three would probably be off-topic). You may think 'fancy' is a clear definition, but others do not. And when you do edit, you decline to provide any information that might help potential answerers, but instead object to the way the site works.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You have asked for "an old old English word" and  "marketing/business/technology terms".  Hence my downvote.

Comment: @TimLymington et al. I am new to this forum, please respect that.

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus?

Comment: Are you sure the word is written *benifit*... People are downvoting the spelling. It's spelled (or spelt) [**benefit**: *from Latin benefactum "good deed,"*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=benefit)

Comment: An Old English word like  [*helpan*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/helpan#Old_English) might be what you are looking for. But we don't know! EDIT: Despite the English sounding name, you aren't British are you?

Comment: Okay, you need it for a heading. **What heading**? _Benefit_ means at least a dozen different things; how is anyone supposed to know which one you’re looking for when the closest definition of what you’re looking for is that it’s in a heading similar to “Introduction”, and “in context with usage of certain technologies and a products increase of benefits” (which, sorry to say, does not make any sense at all)? Even though your intended use is a header, you can still make up an example sentence that would reflect the _meaning_ you’re looking for. A header also has to have some meaning. →

Comment: → For example, if what I suspect might be the intended meaning is in fact what you’re looking for, an example sentence could be, “These are the benefits [to the user? to society in general? etc.] of using this new technology”.

Comment: @Mari-LouA relax, I see that I made a spelling error, some times I am very fast when I type using a keyboard, as right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Godsend:** *(n.)* an unexpected thing or event that is particularly welcome and timely, as if sent by God.
**Benefaction:** *archaic*. an act of conferring a benefit
**egg in one's beer:** *(cool factor)* a bonus, something for nothing

[[Thesarus.com]](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/benefit)

Comment: I am thinking of more marketing/business/technology terms but with some fancy way of putting it to the paper (or actually Word).

Comment: What's your sentence ?

Comment: It's used in Heading, "Introduction", and then after all of the Introduction part, comes "Benefits" except replaced with something fancier.

Comment: Do you have anything further to add?

Comment: Did you try the link ?

Comment: I guess you better stick with beneficium then.

Comment: If you could add a more formal expression, perhaps look under "help/advance" in the thesaurus link, I think it would help the OP. You might even get an upvote from someone else...

Comment: You didn't solve my problem, but you were kind. Respect to you dude!

Answer (score -1):

**Beneficium**. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beneficium, seems like this has to be my final choice. Especially since I am unable to find other words that fit in for a Heading.